# Embed plotly graphs

Tags: javascript, python, plotly

so I know that with plolty and chart studio we can save our plots online and then have an embedded link ready but there is a file limit and after publishing three small plots I get errors and can't publish anything else.

Is there any chance I either convert Plotly graph as javascript (as it's built with JS) and then save that somewhere to embed it later? I'm still very new to this and don't understand everything from it.

My end goal is to embed my Plotly graphs in an article. Any help?

Comment: you want to keep it interactive as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options to export a ploty graph to be used elsewhere:

- **as a static image** - once you have your `fig` you would use `fig.write_image()` and then embed that image in your article/website/etc.  The details and options are detailed [here](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/).

or

- **as interactive html** - once you have your `fig` you would use `fig.write_html("path/to/file.html")` and then embed that html in your site (I think an iframe would be used in this case).  The details and options are detailed [here](https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/).

Comment: @Marc did the above work? Have you tested in the article?